# Spark shell use only 2 executors of 3 for small job, and data is NODE_LOCAL instead of PROCESS_LOCAL

Tags: apache-spark

I use spark2.2 and I launched spark-shell like this:

```
bin/spark-shell --master spark://localhost:7077  --executor-memory 6G
```

Bellow is the UI information.
[image]

**Question 1**
I launch **sc.range(0, 1024 * 1024 + 10, 1).collect** and all 3 cores are invovled, which is normal for me.
Then I would like to do word count on a text file of 60MB. What is bizzard is the **number of partition** is automatically **2** and only 2 executors are used for computation.
Map stage:
[image]
Collect stage:
[image]

**Question 2**
If you look at the locality for **map** and **collect**, you will see **PROCESS_LOCAL** for map and **NODE_LOCAL** for another. Why is the second one **NODE_LOCAL**? I know if it is **NODE_LOCAL**, it means the data is not in the jvm process which treats them, but why? Why does not one of the executor take the data from another executor and save part of the shuffle?

**UPDATE**: I tried with a file of 166MB and this time spark uses all 3 cores for the tasks. SO I guess the usage of 2 or 3 is decided by spark and if it thinks 3 cores are too many for a small job, it will take only 2. I hope someone can explain to me how this decision is been made inside spark, the code or the theory.